# Ios App distribution for a small company by app store

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am developing an ios app. Till now i followed adhoc distribution using testflight for distributing builds to clients. This process creating so many problems like making the builds ever time if i recieves the Device UDID .So I want to submit it to app review process. to go to app review process i have a  few query about that

We are developing this app for a company which is not located in Volume purchase program countries.so we can't distribute via B2B. In future we might give the same app to various clients also. so my queries are

1. The app has login id and password is there. so everyone can't use this . will apple accepts this app . if so ,should i do anything for that. if not so, what would i do to make it available in app store.

2.In future the app customer base might grow. so if i submit different app with the same app content will apple accepts this. if not, should i do anything in first submission.

3.Is apple mentioned any where about the userbase of app.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly ellaborate more on third point...

Comment: is there any way to restrict the app to be in app store by saying the no of employees in your company are less.why because this app is for internal use of the company.

Comment: No there is nothing like that, you can upload the app useful for one particular user also... Anyhow based on what you are saying it is advisable to go for enterprise distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first point is that if you have a login id and password and if you can provide Apple legitimate proof or the need behind using that the app gets approved. Also the answer to the second question is that you can have different apps with the same app content.

Also if you want to distribute the app to a limited user then go for enterprise distribution... More information on enterprise distribution [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

Comment: if the app useful for companies internal purpose only. Then also it will be accepted.

Comment: In such a case enterprise distribution should be used. Then in that case you need not upload the app to appstore.

Comment: Enjoy! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just mention the The Apple about why you need the User to Login in your Review Notes, while you submit your App, Also, you will be asked a Demo account when you make you Applications in itunesConnect make sure to provide a valid User account Id to apple as they would need it to review your App.

Also If your app is only specific to a single company then you should opt for Enterprise Distribution Program by Apple instead of uploading it to Appstore host it on the said COmpany secure server